Man command broken (MacOS 14.6.1)
Entering "man (anything)" returns "No manual entry for (anything)(anything)", e.g. "man man" return "No manual entry for manman".
I've tried new shells, deleting /etc/man.conf, scrutinizing man -ddd output, moving ~/.bash_profile and ~/.profile, etc.  No luck.
So I:

Copied /usr/bin/man to a separate directory and re-ran it -- same
issue
Found the error message: echo "No manual entry for $1" >&2
Put a bunch of these around it:  echo "v1 is $1 on $LINENO"

... and it looks like $1 is changing during a bash function call -- this code:
1396        echo "v1 is $1 on line $LINENO"
1397        man_find_and_display "$page"
....

586  man_find_and_display() {
587      echo "v1 is $1 on line $LINENO"
....

... returns:
v1 is man on line 1396
v1 is manman on line 587
No manual entry for manman

There are no other calls to this function, how is $1 changing during a simple function call?
(MacOS 14.6.1)

what does alias man return?

Turn on man's debugger- man -d man. Anything interesting?

"how is $1 changing during a simple function call?" – $1 inside the function comes from the arguments of the function. Now it seems that for some reason $page expands to manman in the line 1397. Investigate where this value of $page comes from.

Does man d show you the manual of dd?

bash: alias: man: not found

Yes!!  Thank you, Kamil!  Apparently man uses seq, and I had a custom "seq" that I wrote myself on my path that apparently behaves very differently from the built-in one.  I would've thought that built-in tools like man would use absolute paths to their dependencies, but apparently not.  Problem solved.

The problem here was that I had a custom seq tool on my path ahead of the built-in version at /usr/bin/seq.  Once I moved it out of the way, the man pages started working again.
